# JQuery dialog 'data' error on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am using a jQuery dialog, when I close the dialog with the corner X, in IE8 I am getting the following JavaScript error -

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'data(...)' is null or not an object
```

The error is occurring in jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js on this line of code -

```
function(s){e._allowInteraction(s)||(s.preventDefault(),t(".ui-dialog:visible:last .ui-dialog-content").data(i)._focusTabbable())}
```

My dialog is defined as follows -

```
$("#myForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().css('top', '55px');
    },
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
         //code here - commented out still get error
         return true;
    },
    close:function (event, ui) {
         //code here - commented out still get error
         return true;
    }
});
```

Chrome and FireFox work fine.
Any idea what could be causing this error?
Thanks very much!

Comment: There is usually a semicolon missing or an extra comma when you generate errors that refer to jquery's library. I don't see errors here.
Run a javascript debug in IE (7-8) and see if it refers to a line number.

Comment: Thanks so much, Daniel! Can you tell me what you mean by "Run a javascript debug"? Do you mean with the IE Developer tools?

Comment: Yes .. In IE you can press F12, which will show you a window on the bottom. You can subtract extra information there. In particular the "console". You can also choose to debug javascript. More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ... If you develop, you should really start to use these tool. A great help :)

Comment: Do you have this page online on a webserver?